# why my navigation.setOptions doesn't work?

Tags: react-native

I use `react native`.

Please look through my code.

I make const of `HeaderRight`.

and in `useEffect` I call `setOptions` to put HeaderRight const to `headerRight`.

```
const HeaderRight = () => {
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <SmallButton
        styleB={{ backgroundColor: `${colors.light}` }}
        styleBT={{ color: `${colors.gray}`, fontSize: 20 }}
        text={"사진변경"}
        onPress={() => {}}
      />
      <View style={{ width: 10 }}></View>
      <SmallButton
        styleB={{ backgroundColor: `${colors.normal}` }}
        styleBT={{ color: `${colors.lightgray}`, fontSize: 20 }}
        text={"확인"}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    </View>;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: HeaderRight,
    });
  }, []);
```

But nothing show on headerRight on my expo UI.
What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, you forgot to use return in your `HeaderRight` component!

Comment: Ahhhh... my bad  thanks!!!